# data are copied to column instead of row

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

below is the code which is used to copy all the rows from one csv file and paste it in another csv file.

```
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
    Set combineCSV = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("e:\combineCSV.csv")

    nextrow = combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").SpecialCells(11).Row+1

    xlWkb.WorkSheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

    combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Cells(nextrow+1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)

    xlWkb.Close  

    combineCSV.Save
    combineCSV.close


combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Cells(nextrow+1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll) line

nextrow value is 15
```

`nextrow+1 is 16`. the data copied must be pasted in workbook 1 from 16 row, but instead it pastes from 16 column, why it is so??

tried:

`Cells(nextrow+1, 1)` -> it not copying rows at all???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying the 16th cell in the csv, which will be P1. Change:

```
combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Cells(nextrow+1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)
```

to:

```
combineCSV.Worksheets(1).Cells(nextrow+1, 1).PasteSpecial(xlPasteAll)
```

Comment: no still it paste the values from 16th columns on 1 row.

Comment: Woops, backwards! Try now.

Comment: got it. actually i made a mistake nextrow was a string, need to convert it to integer with CInt function does it. Thanks for your reply.